# Joining two strings with delimiters

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to join two strings together that have comma delimiters. I want to loop it so that it becomes consecutive, meaning that the first item in string one before the comma is then followed by the first item in string two and so on. Here is the two strings and how I would want them to join.

```
String 1 = 0,E,EEE,0,0,WWWW,EE,W,EE
String 2 = 0,NNN,N,SS,0,S,N,N,SS

Outcome = 00,ENNN,EEEN,0SS,00,WWWS,EEN,WN,EESS
```

Is this even possible? I have the code to join the two strings but it doesn't put them in the order I'm needing.

Comment: Convert them to 2 string arrays and iterate adding each index to build a String using a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split one and two by `,` and then use `IntStream` to generate the indices of your two token arrays and join the elements by concatenation and then `,`. Like,

```
String a = "0,E,EEE,0,0,WWWW,EE,W,EE", b = "0,NNN,N,SS,0,S,N,N,SS";
String[] aTok = a.split(","), bTok = b.split(",");
String out = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(aTok.length, bTok.length))
        .mapToObj(i -> aTok[i] + bTok[i]).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(out);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
00,ENNN,EEEN,0SS,00,WWWWS,EEN,WN,EESS
```

Answer (score 1):

Split each string into a string array, 
concatenate the items of the same index in both tables and append a `,` after each pair:

```
String s1 = "0,E,EEE,0,0,WWWW,EE,W,EE";
String s2 = "0,NNN,N,SS,0,S,N,N,SS";

String[] tokens1 = s1.split(",");
String[] tokens2 = s2.split(",");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < tokens1.length; i++) {
    sb.append(tokens1[i]).append(tokens2[i]).append(",");
}

sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // remove the last ","

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Of course this works only if the 2 strings can be split in the same number of items.